# How to incorporate hip and core strength work in my workouts

Tags: workout-routines, core, hip

I am a little confused about the best way to incorporate some hip and core strength work in my workout regimen. I am 48, and I am lifting weights 3-4 times per week mostly to gain muscle. So I have a split like back+biceps, chest+triceps, legs, and shoulders. I probably lift for about 30 minutes, and am trying to include a little light cardio like 15-20 minutes on the exercise bike. One the other days, I generally swim or hike, with at least 1 days where allow a lot more rest and recovery.

So I realize that sit a lot for work, so I do need to do more work on my hips and core, but I am not sure how to incorporate these into my existing routine. I am pretty tired on my lifting days, and really overloading my cardio days probably means not enough recovery. So I need to find the right balance.

The most logical substitution would be to swap the cardio on my lifting days with some of this hip and core work. But I am not sure if I will have the energy for that. Like I will have enough energy to do things like kettlebell swings and monster walks with a band on my lifting days, but other stuff like planks or hyperextensions, etc., are probably going to exceed my capacity.

Or, I could just add a 5th day to my lifting cycle, or maybe just include this core and hip work on the shoulder day, which is usually less intense.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to incorporate this kind of core and hip work into their existing routines? Thanks.

UPDATE:
When I refer to hips, I am talking about the muscles the encircle the hip girdle. So some of those muscles include the glute medius, hip adductors, hip flexors, then there are the spinal erectors, and of course the core muscles like obliques. I do have a leg day where I do split squats and hamstring work, among other things. But I don't feel like I target these peripheral hip muscles specifically.

Comment: What do you mean by hips? The hip is a joint, not a muscle. What muscle group(s) are you talking about?

Comment: Sure, I can clarify in the post. So I am using the term "hips" in a kinda loose sense. So this would include lower back things like good mornings and sandbag romanian deadlifts, as well as side leg raises, kettlebell windmills, can core work like leg raises and bridging. So some of these exercises are glute medius, erector spinae, obliques, etc. Some of these get worked on leg day, but not adequately.

Comment: Gotcha. So basically everything legs that isn’t calves and quads, plus lumbar extensors and other core muscles.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. Those muscle do get worked a bit on leg day, but I don't feel like I focus on them enough. I also have to be a bit careful since I am really working on calf and ankle strength--since I have really flat feet--so that is my limiting factor on leg day. So I have to be careful about going too heavy on leg day because my knees get hammered due to weak ankles. But I am working on it :).